# Yii submitButton i18n

Tags: javascript, internationalization, yii

I found how to i18n the message of the submit button like :

```
echo CHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('tr','Print'),array('confirm'=>Yii::t('tr','Please confirm printing'),));
```

Then setting language also translate well the system messages
but how to translate the CANCEL / OK buttons of the submit confirm pop up message box ?

Comment: You can't, it's a javascript feature. You also can't customize the title of the pop-up window, it will always say something like `the page at URL says:`.

Comment: tks this is the answer I was needed ! I just haven't try it on localized browser ! Just do now and it works perfectly...

Comment: You could alternatively use cjuidialog, it won't be exactly like the standard browser/js confirm dialog, but with some tweaking you can make something similar. lemme know if you'd like an example.

Comment: Also a nice idea ! I haven't explore yet the jui widgets but it looks clearly a good way if need to bypass javascript standard messages.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution using [CJuiDialog](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog):

1. Code for the [jqueryui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)(CJuiDialog is a wrapper with some additional yii specifics):

   ```
   <?php
       $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
           'id'=>'mydialog',
           // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
           'options'=>array(
               'title'=>Yii::t('tr', 'Title'),
               'autoOpen'=>false,
               'modal'=>true,
               'closeOnEscape'=>true,
               'closeText'=>Yii::t('tr', 'Cancel'),
               'resizable'=>false,
               'buttons'=>array(
                   Yii::t('tr', 'Ok')=>'js:function(){$("#myform-id").submit();$(this).dialog("close");}',
                   Yii::t('tr', 'Cancel')=>'js:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}'
               )
           ),
       ));

       echo Yii::t('tr','Please confirm printing');

       $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
   ?>
   ```
2. Make this dialog appear for the `onclick` event of the submit button:

   ```
   echo CHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('tr','Print'),array('onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;'));
   ```

Ofcourse this dialog will not look anything like the default browser/js confirm dialog, but it can be used if required. As already mentioned by ors in the comments, **the default confirm dialog can not be changed, and a localized browser should have localized messages.**

In this sample i have just submitted a form with id `myform-id` , however anything can be done in the ok button's function.

Comment: as, i said before, this is an alternate solution. do lemme know if you need any clarifications.