# Yii confirm dialog extension

Tags: php, yii

is there any Yii extension for confirm box?

```
CHtml::link(Yii::t('VehicleModule.app', 'Cancel transfer of the vehicle'), array('/vehicle/vehicle/transfer', 'vehicleId'=>$data->id, 'cancel' => 1), array('confirm'=>Yii::t('VehicleModule.app', 'Are you sure you want to cancel the re-registering of the vehicle?')))
```

I want it styled. Make it like jqueryui dialog.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406951/720508) for using CJuiDialog for doing something similar

Comment: you are welcome, always glad to help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii has CJuiDialog widget which can complete you requirement.

[Yii CJuiDialog Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog)